# C++ matrix class follow up

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented

This is a matrix class with addition and multiplication. I tried incorporating all the helpful advice I got on my previous attempt [C++ matrix class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/255061/c-matrix-class) , specifically using std::vector for memory management, overloading operators, adding error messages and adhering to the rule of 5.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class Matrix {
public:

    // Default constructor
    Matrix();

    // Constructor
    Matrix(int m, int n, std::vector<T> data): rows_{m}, columns_{n} {
        if (m*n != (int) data.size()) {
            throw "Dimensions do not match data!";
        }
        data_ = data;
    }
    
    // Copy constructor (makes a copy of the argument)
    Matrix(const Matrix<T>& other): rows_{other.rows_}, columns_{other.columns_} {
        data_ = other.data_;
    }
    
    // Move constructor (moves the information of the argument to the created object, the 
    // argument is destroyed)
    Matrix(Matrix<T>&& other): rows_{other.rows_}, columns_{other.columns_}, data_{other.data_} {
        other.data_.~vector();
    }
    
    // Copy assignment operator (overloads = when we have an object on the other side of =)
    Matrix<T>& operator=(const Matrix<T>& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            rows_ = other.rows_;
            columns_ = other.columns_;
            data_ = other.data_;
        }
        
        return *this;
    }
    
    // Move assignment operator (overloads = when we have a reference on the other side =)
    Matrix<T>& operator=(Matrix<T>&& other) {
        if (this != &other) {
            rows_ = other.rows_;
            columns_ = other.columns_;
            data_ = &other.data_;
            other.data_.~vector();
        }
        
        return *this;
    }
    
    // Destructor
    ~Matrix() {
        data_.~vector();
    }
    
    // Returns a reference to the entry at (i, j), so we can change it.
    T& operator()(int i, int j) {
        return data_.at(columns_*i + j);   
    }
    
    Matrix<T> operator+(const Matrix<T>& other) {
        if (columns_ != other.columns_ || rows_ != other.rows_) {
            throw "Addition failure: dimensions do not match";
        }
        
        // (Why doesn't 'Matrix<T> sum = this' work as an application of the copy constructor?)
        Matrix<T> sum(rows_, columns_, data_);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows_*columns_; i++) {
            sum.data_[i] += other.data_[i];
        }
        
        return sum;
    }
    
    // Design question: how can I change operator() to allow other to be constant?
    Matrix<T> operator*(Matrix<T>& other) {
        if (columns_ != other.rows_) {
            throw "Multiplication error: dimensions do not match";
        }
        
        std::vector<T> product;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < rows_; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < other.columns_; j++) {
                T sum = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < columns_; k++) {
                    sum += other(k, j) * this->operator()(i, k);
                }
                product.push_back(sum);
            }
        }
        
        return Matrix(rows_, columns_, product);
    }
    
private:
    int rows_;
    int columns_;
    std::vector<T> data_;
    
    template<typename U>
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outputStream, Matrix<U>& matrix);
};

template<typename U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outputStream, Matrix<U>& matrix) {
    
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows_; i++) {
        outputStream << '{';
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix.columns_ - 1; j++) {
            outputStream << matrix(i, j) << ", ";
        }
        outputStream << matrix(i, matrix.columns_ - 1) << "}\n";
    }
    
    return outputStream;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> data{1, 2, 3, 4};
    Matrix<int> mat(2, 2, data);
    
    Matrix<int> sum = mat + mat;
    Matrix<int> product = mat * mat;
    
    std::cout << mat << "+\n" << mat << "=\n" << sum;
    std::cout << "------------------" << std::endl;
    std::cout << mat << "*\n" << mat << "=\n" << product;
    
    mat(0, 0) = 0;
    std::cout << "Changed mat:\n" << mat;
}
```

Comment: If you use `std::vector` the compiler generated copy and move constructor, copy and move assignment is okay,  you do not need to redefine it except you manually manage your memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The default constructor `Matrix()` is declared, but I don't see it defined anywhere. It should initialize `rows_` and `columns_` to zero.
- Throwing a `std::runtime_error` or `std::invalid_argument` exception object would be better than a plain string literal (it's useful to have type information about what went wrong, and easier to use when `catch`ing, since they derive from `std::exception`).
- The move and copy constructors and assignment operators do the same things that we can make the compiler generate with `= default;`:

  ```
  Matrix(const Matrix&) = default;
  Matrix(Matrix&&) = default;
  Matrix& operator=(const Matrix&) = default;
  Matrix& operator=(Matrix&&) = default;
  ```

  Note that inside the class, we can use `Matrix` to mean the same as `Matrix<T>`.
- **bug:** We must not call the vector destructor explicitly (e.g. `data_.~vector()`). Member destructors (i.e. including the `data_` destructor) are called automatically after the class destructor. We don't need to do it manually. This means we can omit the `~Matrix()` function, as the compiler generated version will work fine.
- We need a `const` version of the element access operator, i.e. `T const& operator()(int i, int j) const;`. This allows us to access elements in a `const Matrix` object. (Note: this is why `operator*` doesn't currently work with a `const Matrix&`).
- To invoke the copy constructor inside `operator+`, we need `Matrix sum = *this;` (Remember that `this` is a pointer so we have to dereference it).
- We should use `std::size_t`, not `int`, for `rows_` and `columns_` and the corresponding index arguments. This matches the `size_type` of our vector member. It's also safer: right now `Matrix(-2, -2, { 0, 1, 2, 3 })` doesn't trigger the size check exception!
- We could do with some more functionality: it would be useful to have `const` member functions to return the number of `rows()`, `columns()` and the overall `size()` (`rows() * columns()`).

  We could also add `begin()`, `end()`, `rbegin()` and `rend()` functions, so that we could iterate over all the members in a matrix easily (e.g. `for (auto v : matrix)`). These could call the corresponding `std::vector` member functions and return `std::vector<T>::iterator`s.

Comment: It is very ill advised to make move-ctor/assignment to be defaulted in such cases. As then moved-from object is in an invalid state where rows/cols don't match with the vector it contains leading to variety of bugs that users will encounter. While it is not strictly required by the language standard, it is a poor design choice.